# This page isn’t working right now , localhost redirected you too many times. To fix this issue, try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to run my login page in the browser(chrome, microsoft edge) using nodejs ,ejs ,mongoose but when i enter the adress like(localhost:5000/dashboard/login)  it show me this error (This page isn’t working right nowlocalhost redirected you too many times.
To fix this issue, try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

I've tried to reset the setting , clear history and cookies

Comment: Does your node code have any `res.redirect` in it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: function checkNotAdmin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.redirect('/dashboard/1');
    }
    next();
}

function checkIsAdmin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/dashboard/login');
}